# (webpack & babel) Unexpected token, expected "{"

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-5, babel-loader

There is this code:

```
enum StatusFieldEnum {
    WAITING = 'waiting',
    DELIVERED = 'delivered',
    FAILED = 'failed',
}

export const PurchaseStatusHelper = (
    status: StatusFieldEnum,
): StatusFieldEnum => {
    switch (status) {
        case StatusFieldEnum.FAILED: {
            return errorCode.indexOf('WAS_EXPIRED') != -1
                ? StatusFieldEnum.PAYMENT_WAS_EXPIRED
                : status;
        }

        default: {
            return status;
        }
    }
};
```

But when building with **webpack 5** I get the following error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "{" (1:7)
    
> 1 | enum StatusFieldEnum {
    | ^
  2 |     WAITING = 'waiting',
  3 |     WAITING_CONFIRM = 'waiting_confirm',
  4 |     IN_DELIVERY = 'in_delivery',
```

**babel** included. Uses the following presets and plugins:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-flow",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "const-enum",
        "react-remove-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Tell me, please, what could be the problem? **Thank you very much in advance!**